# Hibernate is not rollbacking generated Id when saving an object

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

```
Here is my sample Entity

@Entity
@Table (name = "company"})
public class Company implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column (name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "company_contact", 
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "companyId") }, 
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "contactId") })
    private List<Contact> contacts;
}

@Entity
@Table (name = "contact")
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 637603479937829299L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = Contact.COLUMN_ID, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = Contact.COLUMN_NAME, unique = true)
    private String name;

}
```

Now when i am trying to save this object, and both the object has same value for the **name** property. Hibernate throws unique constraint exception and once when save the same object hibernate throws batch update failed exception because the id set by the hibernate to the object is not removed.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example how you save the objects and how you handle the rollback?

Comment: I dont think it's because of Hibernate, but because of the SQL ID Unique Field. In your case the ID acts as a Unique PK field, try setting Auto increment on the ID PK.

Comment: Can you show us the value of ``Contact.COLUMN_ID`` and ``Contact.COLUMN_NAME``please ?

Comment: In addition to what previous folks said, can you also post the complete error message and the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are trying to save a company with a list of contacts, both objects having the same name you mean the company having name="Jose" and the contact having the name="Jose" ?

This is not a problem, as we are speaking about TWO DIFFERENT tables (company <> contact) check if your database already have this entities.

So check twice and if still you have problems please put the whole exception stacktrace and what are you trying to do (but a code snippet).

Answer (score -2):

if you save two objects that have the same name, this exception will be thrown

change this :

```
@Column (name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
```

to this :

```
@Column (name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
```

Comment: The two name are not in the same table